I get the error that there is nothing available
I get the following error in the project I developed using React and Typescript.

export 'useTableProps' (reexported as 'useTableProps') was not found in './useTable' (possible exports: useTable)

It says that UseFormProps cannot be found inside the hook named useForm.
However, UseFormProps is present in useForm and even exported.
Is there a mistake in its definition? Why could I be getting this error?
export type useTableProps<TQueryFnData, TError, TSearchVariables, TData> =
  useTablePropsCore<TQueryFnData, TError, TData> & {
    onSearch?: (data: TSearchVariables) => CrudFilters | Promise<CrudFilters>;
  };

To avoid getting the error, I put this type definition in the comment line and this time I get the error that another type cannot be found.

Make sure you are actually exporting useTableProps from your useTable module. Are you using export { useTableProps };?

Yes.
export { useTable, useTableProps, useTableReturnType } from "./useTable";

I then perform this export from within an index.ts file.
